# Python text-based fighting game

Tags: python, python-2.x, battle-simulation

I wrote a fighting game. My code is rough. I would appreciate constructive and critical feedback please. The goal is to become a better programmer/developer.

(I wrote this using 2 Files - The Main Game File & Then a Character File):

**pyfight_characters.py**

```
import math
import random

class Berserker(object):
        MAX_hp = 250
        base_hp = 250
        base_speed = 75
        priority = 'Normal'
        mindset_multiplier = 1.00
        move = ''

        def Jab(self,opponent):
            """ Jab - A fast, light attack. Does 30 Basic Damage to Opponent"""
            self.priority = 'Fast'
            opponent.base_hp -= math.floor( 30*self.mindset_multiplier )

        def Haymaker(self,opponent):
            """ Haymaker - A Slow, strong attack. Does 65 Base to Opponent and 30 Base Damage to User"""
            self.priority = 'Slow'
            opponent.base_hp -= math.floor (65*self.mindset_multiplier)
            self.base_hp -= math.floor(30*self.mindset_multiplier)

        def PumpUp(self,opponent):
            """ PumpUp - Normal speed. Improves the Mindset of the User ( x 1.25 )"""
            self.priority = 'Normal'
            self.mindset_multiplier *= 1.25

        move_pool = {'1':Jab,'2':Haymaker,'3':PumpUp}

class Yogi(object):
        MAX_hp = 220
        base_hp = 220
        base_speed = 80
        priority = 'Normal'
        mindset_multiplier = 1.00
        move = ''

        def Sukha(self,opponent):
            """ Sukha - A Normal speed move. Restores up to a Base of 30 HP to User"""
            self.priority = 'Normal'

            if self.base_hp<=self.MAX_hp:
                self.base_hp += math.floor(30*self.mindset_multiplier)
            else:
                self.base_hp = self.MAX_hp

        def Dukha(self,opponent):
            """ Dukha - A Normal-speed attack. Does 40 Base Damage to the Opponent"""
            self.priority = 'Normal'
            opponent.base_hp -= math.floor(40*self.mindset_multiplier)

        def Meditate(self,opponent):
            """ Meditate - A Normal-speed move. Improves the Mindset of the User (x 1.35)"""
            self.priority = 'Normal'
            self.mindset_multiplier *= 1.35

        move_pool = {'1':Sukha,'2':Dukha,'3':Meditate}

class Trickster(object):
        MAX_hp = 175
        base_hp = 175
        base_speed = 100
        priority = 'Normal'
        mindset_multiplier = 1.00
        move = ''

        def Bag_o_tricks(self,opponent):
            """ Bag-O-Tricks - A Normal-speed move. Increases or Decreases Opponent HP anywhere from 0 to 100 and User HP from 0 to 50"""
            self.priority = 'Normal'
            opponent.base_hp -= math.floor ( random.uniform(-1,1)*100*self.mindset_multiplier )
            if opponent.base_hp > opponent.MAX_hp:
                opponent.base_hp = opponent.MAX_hp

            if self.base_hp <= self.MAX_hp:
                self.base_hp += math.floor ( random.uniform(-1,1)*50*self.mindset_multiplier )
            else:
                pass

            if self.base_hp > self.MAX_hp:
                self.base_hp = self.MAX_hp

        def Tease(self,opponent):
            """ Tease - A Normal-speed move. Reduces the Mindset of the Opponent (x 0.8)"""
            self.priority = 'Normal'
            opponent.mindset_multiplier *= 0.9
            self.mindset_multiplier *= 1.05

        def Swapper(self,opponent):
            """ Swapper - A Normal-speed move. Swaps the User HP with the Opponent HP"""
            self.priority = 'Normal'
            self.base_hp, opponent.base_hp = opponent.base_hp, self.base_hp
            self.MAX_hp, opponent.MAX_hp = opponent.MAX_hp, self.MAX_hp

        move_pool = {'1':Bag_o_tricks,'2':Tease,'3':Swapper}
```

**pyfight.py**

```
# PyFight!

import random
import math
import sys
import os
import time
from pyfight_characters import *

class Game(object):

    mode_options = {'1':('Player 1','CPU'), '2':('CPU 1','CPU 2'), '3':('Player 1','Player 2')}
    game_mode = '' # Preallocation
    game_mode_choice = '' # Preallocation and Stroage

    character_options = {'1':Berserker, '2':Yogi, '3':Trickster}
    move_order = '' # Preallocation

    def __init__(self):
        """ """

    def clear_screen(self):
        os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')

    def introduction(self):
        game.clear_screen()
        print """
        ______       ______  _         _      _              
        | ___ \      |  ___|(_)       | |    | |             
        | |_/ /_   _ | |_    _   __ _ | |__  | |_  ___  _ __ 
        |  __/| | | ||  _|  | | / _` || '_ \ | __|/ _ \| '__|
        | |   | |_| || |    | || (_| || | | || |_|  __/| |   
        \_|    \__, |\_|    |_| \__, ||_| |_| \__|\___||_|   
                __/ |            __/ |                       
               |___/            |___/                        """
        time.sleep(0.3)
        game.clear_screen()

    def choose_game_mode(self):
        while True:
            self.game_mode_choice = raw_input("What versus mode would you like to play: \
                \n1) Player v. CPU \
                \n2) CPU1 v. CPU2 \
                \n3) Player 1 v. Player 2 \
                \n0) Exit Game.\n\n")

            game.clear_screen()

            if self.game_mode_choice == '0':
                sys.exit()
            try:
                self.game_mode = self.mode_options[ self.game_mode_choice ]
                return None
            except KeyError:
                print "Please choose one of the listed options.\n"
                time.sleep(1)

    def character_selection(self,controller_index):
        while True:
            character_choice = raw_input("Who should " + self.game_mode[controller_index] + " play as:\
                \n1) The Berserker\
                \n2) The Yogi\
                \n3) The Trickster\
                \n4) Random\
                \n\
                \n0) Exit Game.\n\n")

            game.clear_screen()

            if character_choice == '0':
                sys.exit()
            elif character_choice == '4':
                character_choice = str (random.randint(1,3))

            try:
                return self.character_options[ character_choice ]
            except KeyError:
                print "Please choose one of the listed options.\n"
                time.sleep(1)

    def hp_check(self,controller_1, controller_2):
        if controller_1.base_hp <= 0:
            if controller_2.base_hp >0:
                self.clear_screen
                print "Controller 2 Wins!"
                sys.exit()
            else:
                self.clear_screen
                print "It's a Draw!!!"
                sys.exit()
        elif controller_2.base_hp <= 0:
            self.clear_screen
            print "Controller 1 Wins!"
            sys.exit()
        else:
            pass

    def player_choose_move(self,controller,controller_index):
        while True:
            move_choice = raw_input(self.game_mode[controller_index] + ", choose your move:\
            \n1)" + controller.move_pool['1'].__doc__ + "\
            \n2)" + controller.move_pool['2'].__doc__ + "\
            \n3)" + controller.move_pool['3'].__doc__ + "\n\n")

            try:
                controller.move = controller.move_pool[move_choice]
                return None
            except KeyError:
                game.clear_screen()
                print "Please choose one of the listed options.\n"
                time.sleep(1)

    def comp_choose_move(self,controller):
        controller.move = controller.move_pool[ random.choice( ['1','2','3'] )]

    def priority_and_speed_check(self,controller1,controller2):
        if controller1.priority > controller2.priority:
            return True
        elif controller1.priority == controller2.priority:
            if controller1.base_speed > controller2.base_speed:
                return True
            elif controller1.base_speed == controller2.base_speed:
                return bool ( random.randint(0,1) )
            else:
                return False
        else:
            return False

    def update(self,controller1,controller2):
        print self.game_mode[0], " HP:", str(Player_1.base_hp), "\n", self.game_mode[0], "Mindset: x", str(Player_1.mindset_multiplier), "\n"
        print self.game_mode[1], " HP:", str(Player_2.base_hp), "\n", self.game_mode[], "Mindset: x", str(Player_2.mindset_multiplier), "\n"
        print "\n\n"

    def move_collection(self,controller1,controller2):
        if self.game_mode_choice == '1':
            self.update(Player_1,Player_2)
            self.player_choose_move(Player_1,0)
            self.clear_screen()

            self.update(Player_1,Player_2)
            self.comp_choose_move(Player_2)
            self.clear_screen()

        elif self.game_mode_choice == '2':
            self.update(Player_1,Player_2)
            self.comp_choose_move(Player_1)
            self.clear_screen()

            self.update(Player_1,Player_2)
            self.comp_choose_move(Player_2)
            self.clear_screen()

        else:
            self.update(Player_1,Player_2)
            self.player_choose_move(Player_1,0)
            self.clear_screen()

            self.update(Player_1,Player_2)
            self.player_choose_move(Player_2,1)
            self.clear_screen()

    def move_application(self,controller1,controller2):
        if self.priority_and_speed_check(Player_1,Player_2):
            Player_1.move(Player_1,Player_2)
            self.hp_check(Player_1,Player_2)

            Player_2.move(Player_2,Player_1)
            self.hp_check(Player_1,Player_2)
        else:
            Player_2.move(Player_2,Player_1)
            self.hp_check(Player_1,Player_2)

            Player_1.move(Player_1,Player_2)
            self.hp_check(Player_1,Player_2)

game = Game()
game.introduction()
game.choose_game_mode()

( Player_1, Player_2 ) = ( game.character_selection(0)(), game.character_selection(1)() )
while True:
    game.move_collection(Player_1,Player_2)
    game.move_application(Player_1,Player_2)
```

Comment: @Cornchip All suggestions for improving the code, even trivial observations, should be written as answers, not comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just a review of your characters. As User319 already noted in [his answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/158709/98493), you should make a base `Character` class and inherit from that. I also implemented a `Move` class which is able to deal with most of your standard moves, and can easily be modified to accommodate more complicated moves.

```
class Character(object):

    def __init__(self, name, MAX_hp, base_speed, priority="Normal", mindset_multiplier=1.0, move=''):
        self.MAX_hp = MAX_hp
        self.base_hp = MAX_hp
        self.base_speed = base_speed
        self.priority = priority
        self.mindset_multiplier = mindset_multiplier
        self.name = name

        self.move_pool = {}

    def __repr__(self):
        return "{self.name} - {self.base_hp} / {self.MAX_hp} HP, {self.mindset_multiplier} mindset, {self.base_speed} speed".format(self=self)
```

Each character has a `name` now, which makes building your list of possible characters easier, because you don't need to hard-code them there, anymore.

The `Move` class is slightly more complicated. Its initializer has a lot of keyword arguments, which all default to no change of the corresponding attribute. Just like currently, you can call a move with the attacker as the first and (optionally) the opponent as the second argument.

```
class Move(object):

    def __init__(self, description="", self_damage=0, damage=0, mindset_multiplier=1.0, opponent_mindset_multiplier=1.0, speed_boost=0, opponent_speed_boost=0, priority="Normal"):
        self.__doc__ = description
        self.self_damage = self_damage
        self.damage = damage
        self.mindset_multiplier = mindset_multiplier
        self.opponent_mindset_multiplier = opponent_mindset_multiplier
        self.speed_boost = speed_boost
        self.opponent_speed_boost = opponent_speed_boost
        self.priority = priority

    def __call__(self, attacker=None, opponent=None):
        if attacker is not None:
            attacker.priority = self.priority
            attacker.mindset_multiplier *= self.mindset_multiplier
            attacker.base_speed += self.speed_boost
            attacker.base_hp -= math.floor(self.self_damage *
                                           attacker.mindset_multiplier)
            attacker.base_hp = min(max(attacker.base_hp, 0), attacker.MAX_hp)

        if opponent is not None:
            opponent.mindset_multiplier *= self.opponent_mindset_multiplier
            opponent.base_speed += self.speed_boost
            opponent.base_hp -= math.floor(self.damage *
                                           attacker.mindset_multiplier)
            opponent.base_hp = min(max(opponent.base_hp, 0), opponent.MAX_hp)
```

A possible improvements would be the ability to use place holders in the docstring, so you could write something like:

```
Move(" Jab - A fast, light attack. Does {self.damage} Basic Damage to Opponent",
     damage=30, priority="Fast")
```

With these definitions, your first two classes are quite straight-forward to implement:

```
class Berserker(Character):

    def __init__(self):
        Character.__init__(self, "Berserker", 250, 75)
        self.move_pool = {"1": Move(" Jab - A fast, light attack. Does 30 Basic Damage to Opponent",
                                    damage=30, priority="Fast"),
                          "2": Move(" Haymaker - A Slow, strong attack. Does 65 Base to Opponent and 30 Base Damage to User",
                                    self_damage=30, damage=65, priority="Slow"),
                          "3": Move(" PumpUp - Normal speed. Improves the Mindset of the User ( x 1.25 )",
                                    mindset_multiplier=1.25)}


class Yogi(Character):

    def __init__(self):
        Character.__init__(self, "Yogi", 220, 80)
        self.move_pool = {"1": Move(" Sukha - A Normal speed move. Restores up to a Base of 30 HP to User",
                                    self_damage=-30),
                          "2": Move(" Dukha - A Normal-speed attack. Does 40 Base Damage to the Opponent",
                                    damage=40),
                          "3": Move(" Meditate - A Normal-speed move. Improves the Mindset of the User (x 1.35)",
                                    mindset_multiplier=1.35)}
```

The `Trickster` is slightly more complicated. Here we define two inner classes which inherit from `Move` for his special moves:

```
class Trickster2(Character):

    class Bag_o_tricks(Move):

        def __call__(self, attacker, opponent):
            self.damage = random.uniform(-1, 1) * 100
            self.self_damage = random.uniform(-1, 1) * 50
            Move.__call__(self, attacker, opponent)

    class Swapper(Move):

        def __call__(self, attacker, opponent):
            attacker.priority = self.priority
            attacker.base_hp, opponent.base_hp = opponent.base_hp, attacker.base_hp
            attacker.MAX_hp, opponent.MAX_hp = opponent.MAX_hp, attacker.MAX_hp

    def __init__(self):
        Character.__init__(self, "Trickster", 175, 100)
        self.move_pool = {"1": Trickster.Bag_o_tricks(" Bag-O-Tricks - A Normal-speed move. Increases or Decreases Opponent HP anywhere from 0 to 100 and User HP from 0 to 50"),
                          "2": Move(" Tease - A Normal-speed move. Reduces the Mindset of the Opponent (x 0.8)",
                                    mindset_multiplier=1.05, opponent_mindset_multiplier=0.8),
                          "3": Trickster.Swapper(" Swapper - A Normal-speed move. Swaps the User HP with the Opponent HP")}
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what Sukha is supposed to do, but I'm finding it odd. I *think* what you meant to do was raise the HP, then reset it if it's higher than the max?

It looks like whenever health changes, it's a multiple of the `mindset_multiplier`. I'd suggest having that in a new function such as:

```
def adjust_health(self, amount):
    self.base_hp += math.floor(amount * self.mindset_multiplier)
```

It looks like there are several fields getting initialized to the same thing. I would have a base `Character` class that the other three inherit from. The base class would set default stats and define the `adjust_health` method.

I had trouble figuring out why each character had an empty `move` variable. I'd recommend a comment. Actually, there's probably a better design for that, but I can't think of it atm.

I don't find the "Preallocation" comments useful.

You *might* have a bug in the character variables. Base HP etc don't have self, so that makes them static variables. I think odd things will happen if you have, for example, two Tricksters fight each other.

You can cut down on code re-use in `move_collection()` by having a `choose_move` function that can tell whether the character is human or computer and doing the right thing from there.